# What is this specific way of announcing court orders called?

Tags: word-requests

What is the Japanese word for the action of announcing court orders to the public, by running to the journalists and expanding a piece of rolled paper with the verdict written on it ([like here](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/p1-oi-a-20140522-870x632.jpg))?

In a casual conversation, I wanted to compare a business situation when no details were given to the interested party but the final verdict, and while my description was clear, I still think there must be a proper term for this phenomenon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

専門的な正式名称ではあの紙を「判決等即報用手持幡」と呼び、一部の弁護士はあの行為を「ハタ出し」と呼ぶそうです。

- [「勝訴」の紙の呼び方やルール、そこには知られざるドラマがあった。](http://www.narinari.com/smart/news/2012/09/19041/)

  > 私が属している弁護団では『**ハタ**』と呼んでおり、裁判所前でハタを掲げることは『**ハタ出し**』と呼んでいます。正式には、『判決等即報用手持幡』というらしいのですが、誰もそんな正式名称は使っていません。
- [判決等速報用手持幡](http://www.bengoshi-blog.com/words/item_13225.html)

  > 判決等速報用手持幡（はんけつとうそくほうようてもちばた）とは、弁護士等が裁判所前で掲げる垂れ幕のこと。
  >   裁判の結果を、”勝訴”・”敗訴”・”無罪”・”不当判決”等と端的に伝えるために使用される。
  >   一般的には、”**幡（はた）**”や”**びろーん**”と呼ばれる。
- [アレの名前【世界面白判例集その３】](http://www.legalnet-ms.jp/topics/2014/002237.html)

  > その名も...「びろーん」。
  >   (本当です)
  >   あえてもう一度言いましょう。あの垂れ幕様のお名前、「びろーん」と言います。
  >   (正式名称は判決等速報用手持幡というらしく、略称として**びろーん**や**ハタ**とわれているようです。)

「ハタ」や「びろーん」はあくまで法律関係者の間での俗称であって、一般人が知っている用語は存在しないと思います。普通は「裁判で判決が出た時にカメラの前でびろーんと出すアレ」「勝訴とか不当判決とか書いてある垂れ幕みたいなもの」などと言わないと通じないと思います。